# Copy vector pattern completely from scratch for commercial use, but exactly as those found online?

Tags: vector, copyright, patterns, legal, stock-images

I need a huge range of vector patterns that will be used commercially on merchandise. Since royalty free sites do not allow commercial use for most of their images, I figured I can create patterns from scratch on my own without using their images at all. These would be simple seamless patterns so they aren't exactly difficult to replicate in illustrator. Ex - Chevron and geometrical patterns.

My question is am I still infringing any legal boundaries? I'm not using their image at all for the creation of my image. But they would probably be exactly the same.

Comment: If you designed them from scratch, in other words didnt look at the other design when you were using it then sure. (they wont be exactly the same unless you use exactly same dimensions often even simple patterns get different since you choose some other relations) however if you measure stuff then its technically infringing as its a derivative work. However you might still be infringing for patterns that are more unique. Ask LAW.SE

Comment: Seems kinda contradictory... "I'm not using their image at all for the creation of my image. But they would probably be exactly the same.".

Comment: If a design is basic enough, there is a point where it's considered "public domain". For example, a checkerboard pattern would be considered public domain.

Comment: This is a legal question. We can't provide legal answers. Consult a licensed and reputable legal professional in your jurisdiction about what constitutes fair use versus derivative work. Whether something is legal often comes down to who has the better lawyers, the better legal argument, and finally, the resources to make the legal case.